# What does this mean? (Japanese-English Translation)

Tags: translation

三人はいつものように、炭を売ってしまった後（あと）で、町の居酒屋で一杯ひっかける楽しみのほか、**何の考えもなく足を早めて道を歩いて行きました。**
So it's a story about 3 lonely guys who are peasants from a small village. And on their off time they make charcoal and sell it in town, because their farms are only small and don't make any money. So after they sell their charcoal, they go to the izakaya and.... I don't understand after that.

Answer (score 3):

- 何の考えもなく without a thought
- 足を早めて pick up the pace (lit. hasten/speed up one's feet)
- 道を歩いて行きました。walked down the street

I think you can take it from there.